# how to detect when rendering image finished in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to prepare large image to mount in DOM using decode function but Internet Explorer does not have decode. How can I detect when Internet Explorer decoded image and be ready to mount in DOM?

```
if (bgimageEl.decode) {
 var promise = bgimageEl.decode();
 if (promise) {
  promise.then(function() {
   showElements();
  });
 } else {
  showElements();
 }
}else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support `decode()`. I think we can only use a similar function [`HTMLImageElement.complete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete) to detect whether the image is completely loaded. If yes then we show the image (the image is hide first).

Sample code:

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img')

function loaded() {
  img.style.display = 'block';
  alert('loaded')
}

if (img.complete) {
  loaded()
} else {
  img.addEventListener('load', loaded)
  img.addEventListener('error', function() {
    alert('error')
  })
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/3q3kNGh.png" style="display:none;" />
```